# You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream : Swagger integration with django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, swagger, drf-spectacular

Not able to access request.body after adding extend_schema. Where my message are already consumed i am using standard middleware only that comes with django setup

```
from rest_framework import decorators, serializers
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema, OpenApiParameter, inline_serializer
from drf_spectacular.types import OpenApiTypes
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

```
@extend_schema(
    request=inline_serializer(
        name="MemberSerializer",
        fields={
            "loan_ids": serializers.ListField(),
        },
    ),
    responses=OpenApiTypes.OBJECT,
    methods=['POST'],
)
@decorators.api_view(http_method_names=['post'])
@csrf_exempt
def post_member(request):
    request_body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'request': request_body}, status=200)
```

```
Middlewares :
"django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
"django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
"django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
"django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
"django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
"django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
"django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
```

i don't want to use request.data to fetch the input request data, Wanted to know where i have  consumed the request.body the first time